# Can I use wlan for incoming data and eth0 for outgoing over the same network?

Tags: networking, wifi

I've set up my Raspberry Pi as a NAS system using Samba and i would like to max its possible speed over the network. Is it possible for me to use both `wlan` and `eth0` to connect to the same network, but using them as unidirectional connections so one can send data and the other can receive it? (This way if I start copying media to the NAS it does not effect streaming)

My router assigns the interfaces different ip addresses and they have different MAC addresses too.

Comment: I guess your wifi wil be from a USB dongle.  On the Pi Ethernet is also implemented over USB.  Given that both wlan and eth will be transported over the same USB hardware I do not see that you will gain anything.

Comment: Joan is correct about the shared bus, and if that is (realistically) limited to 240 Mbps total, and your storage is attached via USB, and you are writing/reading from/to storage at the same time, and the ethernet is maxed out at 100 Mbps, then the rest of the USB bandwidth will be used in accessing the storage.  Pretty much.  I would guess you are not even getting that right now, more like 50 - 60 Mbps.  I don't think adding the wifi connection will help, but you can always try.

Comment: It's called "bonding" and Linux-based systems generally support it. I don't have a reference to hand so this isn't good enough (IMO) for a full answer.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there are a few questions involving this but no definitive explanation.   I did [find this](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding), though.   The default rpi kernel does have the `bonding` driver available, so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely most of the today's ethernet connections are full duplex. This means that transmission in both directions is fully parallel, so it makes no sense to disable transmission or receive on ethernet. But it still makes some sense (in theory) to use wifi which is half-duplex as 'additional' channel. It will only be possible and fairly easy to shape outgoing traffic, something like https://serverfault.com/questions/647343/load-balancing-iptables-postrouting-rules should work. In practice that should be interesting experiment, but don't expect much - wifi has far more latency and packet loss than ethernet.